# Socket.io клиент Android

Tags: java, android, socket.io

заранее извиняюсь за возможно нубский вопрос, новичок в java)
и по socket.io нету нормальных туториалов. С гуглом попытался начать осваивать и вроде что-то получилось(Приложение хотя бы запускается xD)
но когда жму кнопку на форме и выполняется `Connect` то краш с ошибкой

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'io.socket.client.Socket io.socket.client.Socket.connect()' on a null object reference
```

Вот что получилось) можете объяснить что не так?

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Socket mSocket;
    {
    try {
        mSocket = IO.socket("192.168.100.3:8080");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {}
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    }


    public void Connect(View v){
        mSocket.connect();
    };
}
```

Comment: Пустой catch блок - причина ваших затруднений. Если вы в нём выведите ошибку, то увидите поему переменная неинициализировалась

Comment: Спасибо, помогло) проблема была в том что не было `http://` перед ip адресом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [комменту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/569269/socket-io-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-andrid?noredirect=1#comment746544_569269), после того, как в `catch` блоке была выведена в консоль ошибка, выяснилось, что в адресе не хватало схемы, т.е. `http://`. Именно в этом была ошибка